# How to render a radial field in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

How would I render a 2D radial field in OpenGL? I know I can render it pixel by pixel but I'm wondering if there are more efficient solutions? I don't mind if it requires OpenGL3+ functionality.

Comment: Would you be using straight lines or curves (I really don't understand what a radial field is...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How familiar are you with shaders? Because I'm thinking an easy-ish answer would be to render a quad and then write a fragment shader to color the quad based off of how far each pixel is from the center.

Pseudocode:

vertex shader:

```
vec2 center = vec2((x1+x2)/2,(y1+y2)/2); //pass this to the fragment shader
```

fragment shader:

```
float dist = distance(pos,center); //"pos" is the interpolated position of the fragment. Its passed in from the vertex shader
//Now that we have the distance between each fragment and the center, we can do all kinds of stuff:
gl_fragcolor = vec4(1,1,1,dist) //Assuming you're drawing a unit square, this will make each pixel's transparency smoothly vary from 1 (right next to the center) to 0 (on the edce of the square)
gl_fragcolor = vec4(dist, dist, dist, 1.0) //Vary each pixel's color from white to black
//etc, etc
```

Let me know if you need more detail

Comment: I am guessing the added efficiency will be based on it being processed in the GPU?

Comment: Yes. This is sth you want to do in shaders.

Comment: The GPU will do all the coloring in parallel, so even though we're rendering the radial field pixel by pixel, we still get a massive speed boost.